# Mongodb javascript variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to use the string value in nodejs in a mongo query. But on passing those variable in [] I get back an undefined object. Putting the actual value however does give the right answer

```
var myquery = [
    { 
        $match: {
            time: {
                $gte: [start_time],
                $lt: [end_time]
            },
            payeeFsp : [dfsp_given]
        }
    },   
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: {$sum:"$amount"}
        }
    }
];
```

```
dbo.collection("transaction_history").aggregate(myquery).toArray(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: suppose if you want to query 2 or more check in start_time. use time: '{$gte: {$in: [start_time]}}'

Comment: can i see the schema of your collection?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put the variables in array?

I think the query should be like this

```
var myquery = [
    { 
        $match: {
            time: {
                $gte: start_time,
                $lt: end_time
            },
            payeeFsp : dfsp_given
        }
    },   
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total: {$sum:"$amount"}
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it returns an undefined object. Using the values directly as a string gives a record like so {_id: "something", "total": "something"}

Comment: send the actual values of `start_time` `end_time` `dfsp_given` please

Comment: The query with the values is [{ $match: {time: {$gte: '2018-06-01T00:00:00',$lt:  '2018-06-02T00:05:00'},payeeFsp : "FDN"  }}, {$group: {_id: null,total: {$sum: "$amount"}}}];

Comment: if `time` field type is Date you should convert your string date to ISODate. [{ $match: {time: {$gte: ISODate('2018-06-01T00:00:00'),$lt: ISODate('2018-06-02T00:05:00')},payeeFsp : "FDN" }}, {$group: {_id: null,total: {$sum: "$amount"}}}]

Comment: Using the query without the ISODate() also returns the correct output. The difficulty is in substituting the string values with a variable